# How can a covering map (as defined in Hatcher) fail to be a surjection?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Hatcher defined a covering space as follows:

$\textbf{Defn:}$ A covering space of a space $X$ is a space $\tilde{X}$ together with a map $p: \tilde{X} \to X$ satisfying the following conditions: There exists an open cover $\{ U_{\alpha}\}$ of $X$ such that for each $\alpha$, $p^{-1}(U_{\alpha})$is a disjoint union of open sets in $\tilde{X}$ each of which is mapped by $p$ homeomorphically onto $U_{\alpha}$

I don't understand how such a map can fail to be surjective. Any concrete examples??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For instance, if $\tilde{X}$ is the empty set, and $p$ is the empty map. Then each $p^{-1}(X)$ is empty, so it is an (empty) disjoint union of open sets, "each" of which are mapped homeomorphically onto $X$ (vacuously, as there are no opens to check the condition on).

Comment: And there are intermediate situations: if $X$ is not connected, one component can be completely outside of the image for this reason.

Comment: This is not correct. The definitions asks that $p$ maps each disjoint open set *onto* $U_\alpha$. This cannot happen in your case, since the image of an empty set is empty.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I think it is correct. The open cover of $\emptyset$ is not the empty set $\{ \emptyset \}$, it is the empty collection of sets $\{ \}$. Each open $U \in \{ \}$ satisfies any condition you want, since there are no opens to check. Do you disagree?

Comment: @area The cover is of the base space, not the covering space.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I was being imprecise. You take the covering $\{X\}$ of the base space. What I mean is that $p^{-1}(X)$ is an empty disjoint union - it is $\cup_{U \in \emptyset} U$. Since there are no opens in this disjoint union to check, vacuously each maps onto $X$.

Comment: No, they don't map onto $X$. The induced map must be an homeomorphism, and it clearly isn't in this case.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I think you are misunderstanding me. It is analogous to the following situation: Let A be a collection of some spaces. In this case, X. Then the empty set is always a disjoint union of spaces in A. How? It is the empty disjoint union. Each set in the disjoint union is homeomorphic to X, but this is only because there are no sets in the disjoint union. There are no induced maps that can fail to be a homeo, so all of them are homeomorphisms. This changes if you require that the preimage is a nonempty disjoint union of open sets in ...

Comment: @PedroTamaroff the covering. But really, this is maximal pedantry, and completely a distraction from the beautiful ideas of covering space theory.

Comment: The empty function is a function to $X$, but it is not an homeomorphism, because it is not onto, say.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I know that the empty function is not a homemorphism. That is not my point.

Comment: @AreaMan OK, I see now what the misunderstanding is. You're allowing to take a union indexed by the empty set, and I wasn't.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Precisely the difference. I am pretty sure that taking empty unions is allowed under standard set theoretic rules... it is a pretty weird thing to do though. If you know some sheaf theory, you can use this trick to figure out what a sheaf of Abelian groups on the empty set has to be.